# boost::shared_ptr as data member, how to assign in the constructor?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, shared-ptr

If you have a boost::shared_ptr data member in a class:

```
class X{
public:

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<Y> a;
};
```

How do you initialise the pointer in the constructor of X? I tried this and it wouldn't work:

```
X::X(){
    a(new Y());
}
```

Comment: "wouldn't work" how? looks good to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the member-initializer list:

```
X::X()
    : a(new Y())
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
{ }
```

Otherwise `a(new Y())` is considered a call to `boost::shared_ptr<Y>::operator()(Y*)` for which there is no definition (or prototype), so you get an error. An alternative solution would be to use assignment:

```
X::X()
{
    a = new Y(); // or a = boost::make_shared<Y>()
}
```